# Knockout.js: how to get current form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new to KnockoutJS and I would like to serialize the current form, but when I console.log the serialized the form, it is empty.

**How can I refer to the current form ?**

Here is my DOM :

```
<form data-bind="submit: onSubmit">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName">
  <button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here, the JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
        self.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
        self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
            return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
        }, self);
        self.capitalizeLastName = function() {
            var currentVal = self.lastName();        // Read the current value
            self.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase()); // Write back a modified value
        };

        self.onSubmit = function(form) {
//            alert( self.firstName()) ;
            console.log($(form).serialize()) ;
        }
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why do you want to serialize the form, when the data should all already be present within your knockout viewmodel?  What's your actual end goal here?

Comment: I am working with a PHP framework in which I post the serialized form. Then the serialized form is automatically recreated on the server ajax method. That's why I want to serialize the current form and not access directly the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly referring to the current form in your code: it gets passed as the first argument to the `submit` data binding handler, however, only `input` with a `name` attribute are serialized by `jQuery.serialize()` method. Add `name` attributes to your fields and it will work.

From https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ (bold is mine)

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. **For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute**. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

However, I would advise you to follow @James Thorpe suggestion in the comments and get the form values from Knockout.js observables instead.

Comment: You are right. It's a jquery problem and not a KO one.